# Error when composing commands

Tags: bash

I obtain the directory of the current file using this code:

```
dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```

I would like to go down one level in the file structure.

For instance if my file is at:

```
/a/b/c/myFile.sh
```

`dir` will be `/a/b/c`

I would like to go to `/a/b`

So I am running this command:

```
containingdir = "$( cd "$dir" && cd ".." && pwd )"
```

However, I'm getting this error on the line where I defined the command:

```
myFile.sh: line 13: containingdir: command not found
```

What's the cause of this error?

Comment: you are saying `var = "$(command)"`, note the spaces around `=`. This is wrong, since it tries to run the command `var` with parameters `"$(command)"`. Just remove those spaces.

Comment: Perhaps `containingdir=$(readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"/..)` would be sufficient...

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`dirname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) (twice if needed):

```
reut@reut:~$ dirname $(dirname /a/b/c/myFile.sh)
/a/b
```